# Expecting an element in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

1/ There are 2 errors in my **blockquote** code, may i know how should I change the code?

1.1/ Kotlin: Expecting an element
1.2/ Kotlin: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public final operator fun minus(other: Byte): Int defined in kotlin.Int

Aim of the classes: add discount product under product with new salesprice

```
class DiscountProduct(
productName: String,
basePrice: Double,
salesPrice: Double,
description: String) :
Product(productName, basePrice, salesPrice, description) {
val discount = mutableListOf(DiscountType.SUMMER, DiscountType.SHORT, DiscountType.ALLAWAY, DiscountType.NODISC)
```

> override var salesPrice: Double = salesPrice*(100-discount)%

```
}

open class Product(
  val productName: String,
  var basePrice: Double,
  open var salesPrice: Double,
  val description: String) {...}


enum class DiscountType(disc:Int) {
  SUMMER(20),
  SHORT(10),
  ALLAWAY(50),
  NODISC(0)
}
```

2/ which topic should I learn to avoid the same error again?

Thank you!

Comment: I started trying to write an answer, but there are so many things wrong here that it was turning into a novel. I suggest reading through the basics of what class properties are, what the difference is between declaring a property inside or outside of the constructor, and what it means to override a property or function. Also, `%` is a remainder operator. It does not divide a number by 100 like you seem to have assumed.

Comment: `discount` is a List of Products. You can't subtract a List of Products from the number 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, in this line, you have two errors

```
override var salesPrice: Double = salesPrice*(100-discount)%
```

At first, you're trying to subtract a list of objects (in your case it's `DiscountType`) from a hundred. It will not work this way. You should tell how exactly you want to do this. For example by writing another function. Something like this:

```
fun getDiscount(discounts : List<DiscountStatus>): Int{
    return 100 - discounts.sumBy { it.disc } 
}
```

Or whatever you want to do with the discounts. Anyway, the compiler doesn't know how to deal with different types (number and a list of `DiscountType` objects).

Second, you're adding a `%` symbol at the end of the statement. In Kotlin there is such an operator but is used in a different way. Probably you want to apply you're `discount` to the `salesPrice`. Again you must tell the compiler how exactly you want to do this. Write a function:

```
fun applyDiscount(price: Double, discount: Int): Double {
    return price * (discount.toDouble() / 100.0)
}
```

Or something similar. An finally combine all this into one statement:

```
val discount = mutableListOf(DiscountType.SUMMER, DiscountType.SHORT, DiscountType.ALLAWAY, DiscountType.NODISC)
override var salesPrice: Double = applyDiscount(salesPrice, getDiscount(discount))
```

Please, do the whole calculation on your own and treat my answer as an example.
And you should really learn basics of Kotlin, starting with arithmetic operations. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html#operators-and-special-symbols

Comment: It looks like only one of the possible discount types should be used at a time, in which case `salesPrice` should either be converted to a function, or `discount` should not be a list, but just one type. And it doesn't make sense that `salesPrice` is `open` when its a primary constructor parameter. And `DiscountType` doesn't have a property declared. I gave up on answering this because there are so many fundamentals to explain.